# Load images to cache- make the iPad crash

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am loading many images to cache, it worked great in simulation till now, that i have tried it on the device - iPad2 , and it do crash, if after the default screen i am loading all the sprites to cache . the app crash even before it starts .

so , i have tried to load it on background , and what happen is that, it do NOT crash now, but some-how i see a black rects instead of the images that i have loaded to cache , means that maybe they havnt loaded anyway .

this is in the init method of the first class :

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadSpriteFrames) withObject:nil];
```

//than

```
-(void)loadSpriteFrames
{
     //pre load effects
      [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"badEffect.mp3"];
      [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"heartEffect.mp3"];
      [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"rewardBig.mp3"];
       [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadBackgroundMusic:@"backgroundTraffic.mp3"];


    //preload images needed for animations
       [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"stopAnim.png"];
      [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"shAnim.png"];
      [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"happyAnim.png"];
      [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:@"grumpyAnim.png"];
    NSLog(@"*****2"); //do log

}
```

Comment: filenames are case sensitive on device. Check the debug console for log messages

Comment: what are the sizes (in pixels) of the images you are loading?